# Office ui Fabric People Picker, pass varaibles to onChangeEvent

Tags: reactjs, spfx, office-ui-fabric, peoplepicker

I would like to know if there is a possibility to added a variable to the default onchange event of the office ui fabric react People Picker component.

In the onchange event default is `onChange?: (items?: IPersonaProps[]) => void`

I would like to pass an variable to add to an array like Key Value for using later in my code.

Comment: @keikai how do you build a HOC? do you have an example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a HOC to achieve this.

Define

```
// Your HOC component

interface Props {
  yourCustomState: string // get custom value from props
...


return (
  <>
    <Select
      onChange={(e: any) => onChange(e, yourCustomState)} // add custom value to callBack function
  ...
```

Usage

```
handleOnChangeEvent = () => (event, yourCustomStateValue: string) => {
  console.log(yourCustomStateValue);
  ... // event
}

<YourComponent
  yourCustomState={value}
  onChange={this.handleOnChangeEvent()}
...
```